# Export CSV with values enclosed with double quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, office-for-mac

How do I export a CSV file where the values and fields are both enclosed in double quotes (") from Excel 2004 (Mac)?

E.g.

```
"Name","Telephone"
"John Doe","555-5009"
```

Comment: Is your data already enclosed in double quotes?  Or is that part of what you need help with?

Comment: I need help enclosing the values in " without having to manually type it in.

Comment: Does your spreadsheet include formulas, or is all the data values only?

Comment: did you get solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**
It only took me close to two years to come back and edit this. Here's a workaround that will hopefully wrap all your data in quotation marks and save as CSV. You will need to add the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference to your VBA project (Under `Tools` > `References...`).

```
Sub addquotes()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim tmpR As Range
Dim tmpArray() As Variant, out As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject, ts As TextStream

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set s = ActiveSheet
Set tmpR = s.UsedRange

'Set format of all cells as Text.
tmpR.NumberFormat = "@"
tmpArray = tmpR.Value

For i = LBound(tmpArray, 1) To UBound(tmpArray, 1)
    For j = LBound(tmpArray, 2) To UBound(tmpArray, 2)
        If j = LBound(tmpArray, 2) Then out = out & Chr(34)
        out = out & tmpArray(i, j) & Chr(34)
        If j <> UBound(tmpArray, 2) Then
            out = out & "," & Chr(34)
        Else
            out = out & vbLf
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Editor 3\Desktop\yourcsv.csv", ForWriting, True)
ts.Write out
ts.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Previous failed attempt (left only for reference; please don't use this):**
Here's a macro that will open a new workbook and enter all the data from your sheet with each value enclosed in quotation marks.  You can then save this new workbook as a .CSV without disturbing your original workbook.  This will work even if your original data included formulas.

```
Sub addquotes()

Dim s As Worksheet, newS As Worksheet
Dim tmpR As Range
Dim tmpArray() As Variant

Set s = ActiveSheet
Set tmpR = s.UsedRange

'Loads all data from sheet into array.
tmpArray = tmpR.Value

'Adds quotes around members of array if not blank.
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(tmpArray, 2)
        If tmpArray(i, j) <> "" Then
            tmpArray(i, j) = """" & tmpArray(i, j) & """"
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'Open new workbook and enter transformed data.
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Set newS = NewBook.Sheets(1)
newS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(tmpArray, 1), UBound(tmpArray, 2)) = tmpArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice start, but it doesn't work.  You get quotes that show up as part of the cell data, rather than just enclosing it.  I.e., something like `"""ID""","""Section""","""Sub-section""","""Title""","""Template""","""Owner/Author""","""URL Fragment""","""URL""","""Initial Content From""","""Status""","""Body""","""Home""","""lang""","""Published""","""User"""`.   This is not what the original poster was asking for.

Comment: @iconoclast Now that I've looked at the CSV in a text editor, I see you're right.  Looks like an edit is in order.  Thanks.